# Minimum number of seats in an office hybrid schedule (formulation problem)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, modeling, schedule

Can anyone help me to understand the type of problem this is, in order to find an online solver?

The problem I want to model is the following. In the company I work for there is a willing to introduce hybrid work and reduce the number of seats, and all the employees are asked the minimum and maximum number of days they need to stay in the office.
My goal is to understand

- first: the minimum number of seats needed in order to have space for everyone
- Secondly: add some constrains related to the need that some colleagues (i.e. a team) needs to stay in the office at the same time, to work together

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!!!

I tried looking at Operational Research problems, but all I have found are similar but not the one actually needed. I imagine I am not the first one that wants to model this problem, probably I just need a reference to a specific type of problem in the OR taxonomy of models...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to design a weekly schedule. I would start with something like

```
   i : employee
   d : day

   min maxseats
       maxseats >= sum(i,x(i,d))                   ∀d
       mindays(i) <= sum(d,x(i,d)) <= maxdays(i)   ∀i
       x(i,d) ∈ {0,1}
```

To handle teams, you need to think a bit about the data. A requirement could look like: a `team(t,i)` with workers i, needs to be on the office `teamdays(t)` per week. With this we could do something like:

```
   min maxseats
       maxseats >= sum(i,x(i,d))                   ∀d
       mindays(i) <= sum(d,x(i,d)) <= maxdays(i)   ∀i
       sum(d, y(t,d)) = teamdays(t)                ∀t   
       x(i,d) >= y(t,d)                            ∀i,t,d|team(t,i)
       x(i,d) ∈ {0,1}   (worker i at office on day d)
       y(t,d) ∈ {0,1}   (team t at office on day d)
```

These are linear MIP models.